# style is not applied

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working in asp.net mvc. I have included multiple JS and CSS files in Layout file. I am using .Load() method of JQuery to load partial pages after click event of a link. Problem is that style is not being applied on elements of partial pages after being loaded.

Comment: `.Load()` should be `load()`, but can you reproduce with a demo?